# Set difference different using single character vs. string atoms?

Tags: python, set

I'm trying to wrap my head around why I get different results from multiple Pythons using set difference, depending on whether the set atoms are single character strings or multiples:

```
x = {'a': 1234, 'b': 2345, 'c': 9998}
y = set(x.keys())
w = {'aa': 1234, 'bb': 2345, 'cc': 9998}
z = set(w.keys())
print('c' in y)
print(y.difference('c'))
print(y.difference(set('c')))

print('cc' in z)
print(z.difference('cc'))
print(z.difference(set('cc')))
```

Produces:

```
True
set(['a', 'b'])
set(['a', 'b'])
True
set(['aa', 'cc', 'bb'])
set(['aa', 'cc', 'bb'])
```

I can't see why they should be different in behaviour.

Comment: ...do you know what `set('cc')` is (*hint*: **not** `{'cc'}`)?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the docs, you'll see that the `set()` constructor takes an `iterable`. Since python strings are iterables, then `set('x')` is effectively the same as `set('xxxxx')`:

`set('x') == set('xxxx')
True  # yes, they are the same`

In your case you probably want `set(['c'])` and `set(['cc'])`.

Comment: Ok but `set(w.keys())` should be returning an iterable of keys, which are strings, hence I'm passing an iterable list of iterables, not a single string. But indeed passing the list of elements to remove is the correct solution, thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. Indeed `z = set(w.keys())` is a set of strings `{'aa', 'bb', 'cc'}`; that's why `'cc' in z == True`. The issue in your original post is that, when computing the set difference, the argument of `z.difference()` is a set. In your example, the set you were passing was `{'c'}` in both cases (in the first case, implicitly and in the second case explicitly). Thus, the difference was the original set `{'aa', 'bb', 'cc'}`, because `'c'` is not a subset of it. Anyway, if you feel either my answer or @ikostia's did answer your question, you should select one as accepted. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `a.difference` expects an iterable of elements to remove from `a`. Thus when you call `y.difference('c')` Python produces a set that is equivalent to `y` but does not contain `'c'`. On the other hand, when you call `z.difference('cc')`, Python produces set that is equivalent to `z` but does not contain `'c'` and does not contain `'c'` (e.g. it iterates over the `'cc'` string for elements to remove).

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, `set('cc')` is a set with one element, `'c'`, not with `'cc'`. If you want a set with `'cc'` as an element, you have to construct it in a way similar to: `set(['cc'])`. If you run `z.difference(set(['cc']))`, you'll see what you expect.